# Microsoft DNS SOA Refresh Interval is grayed out

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-2000

In my DNS, I am getting a zone transferred to my Windows 2000 server.  I would like to change the interval of refresh.  But, I cannot because the entire SOA tab options are grayed out, disabled.  I can click the tab SOA, but I cannot change anything.  How can I change these options for refreshing?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by "getting a zone transferred to my server" you mean that your server runs a slave zone, then yes: you cannot change data on a slave zone.

The data is entirely dictated by the master copy, which you don't control.

Comment: doesn't it go out and query the server that has that zone every so often?

Comment: ...yes, and ? Doesn't change the fact that you cannot change the data of a slave zone.